# How to install maven toll for dependencies in netbeans in windows?

Tags: maven

I recently started a project and learnt that I need to install depended packages manually and i'm very much lazy to do so. I searched and got Maven, but installation process is missing. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest Netbeans from here..

https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Maven is embedded in Netbeans, then you'd only create a new Maven project from the file menu... And you will manage you dependencies easily..

Comment: Then we do not need to install Maven separately , Right?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded NetBeans new version when I try to create a new project, Maven Project is already there.

[image: check this picture]